# Need help to solve taylor series of $e^{\sin x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to derive the taylor series of $e^{\sin x}$, up to $x^5$?

i just don't know how to get the answer
$$f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8} -\frac{x^5}{15}$$

really need some help. Thanks

Comment: If you lack a better idea, why not just compute the first 5 derivatives of $f(x) = e^{\sin x}$, and use that the taylor series around $c$ (by definition!) is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x-c)^n\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}$. Note that $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$ here.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sin x \sim x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}$$

$$e^x \sim 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}  + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{x^5}{120}$$

so $$e^{\sin x} \sim 1 + \sin x + \frac{\sin ^2 x}{2}  + \frac{\sin ^3 x}{6} + \frac{\sin ^ 4 x}{24} + \frac{\sin ^5x}{120} $$

Now substitute the expansion of $\sin x$, and you should get to the result

(remember to eliminate all those terms that have a degree higher than 5! :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = e^{\sin x}$.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f'(x) &= e^{\sin x} \cos x = f(x) \cos x\\
f''(x) &= f'(x) \cos x - f(x) \sin x \\
f'''(x) &= f''(x) \cos x - f'(x)\sin x - (f(x)\cos x + f'(x) \sin x)\\
&= f''(x) \cos x - 2f'(x) \sin x - f'(x)\\
f^4 (x) &= f'''(x) \cos x - f''(x) \sin x - 2(f'(x)\cos x + f''(x)\sin x) - f''(x)\\
&= f'''(x) \cos x - 3f''(x) \sin x - 2f'(x) \cos x - f''(x)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Calculating higher order derivatives at $x=0$,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(0) &= 1\\
f'(0) &= 1 \times 1 = 1\\
f''(0) &= 1 - 0 = 1\\
f'''(0) &= 1-0-1 = 0 \\
f^4 (0) &= 0 - 0 -2 -1 = -3\\
f^5 (0) &= f^4 (0) \cos 0 - 3 f''(0) \cos 0 - 2f''(0) \cos 0- f'''(0)\\
&= - 3 -3-2-0 =-8
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Using Maclaurin's expansion for infinite series,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x) &= f(0) + xf'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0) + \frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(0) + \\
     &  \frac{x^4}{4!}f^4 (0) + \frac{x^5}{5!}f^5 (0) + \frac{x^6}{6!}f^6 (0) +  \ldots\\
e^{\sin x} &= 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}\times 1 + 0 + \frac{x^4}{4!}\times (-3) + \frac{x^5}{5!} \times (-8) \ldots\\
&= 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^5}{15} \ldots\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
f(x) = a_1x + \frac{a_2}{2}x^2 + \frac{a_3}{6} x^3 + \frac{a_4}{24} x^4 + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n + \cdots
$$
then
$$
e^{f(x)} = 1 + a_1 x + \frac{a_2+a_1^2}{2!} + \frac{a_3 + 3a_2a_1+a_1^3}{6} x^3 + \frac{a_4+4a_3a_1 + 3a_2^2 + 6a_2a_1 + a_1^4}{24} x^4 + \cdots 
$$

The pattern is this: Consider the last case shown above, where $n=4$.  There are several ways to partition the number $4$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{integer partition} & \text{number of set partitions} \\
\hline
4 & 1 \\
3+1 & 4 \\
2+2 & 3 \\
2+1+1 & 6 \\
1+1+1+1 & 1
\end{array}
$$
The numbers of set partitions are the coefficients.  See this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula

Now try this with
$$
a_1 = 1,\quad a_2=0,\quad a_3=-1,\quad a_4=0,\quad a_5=1,\quad\ldots\ldots
$$

$$
e^{\sin x} = 1 + x + \frac 1 2 x^2 + \frac{(-1)+0+1^3}{3} x^3 + \cdots 
$$